# How to create a multiline textfield in Reportlab?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm using Reportlab to generate PDF with an interactive textfield. However, I would like to give the possibility for the user to write multiple lines in this textfield and I couldn't find a way to do that. Suppose I have the following code :

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def add_textfield(c):
    c.acroForm.textfield('test', maxlen=1000, x=50, y=500, width=500, height=300)


c = canvas.Canvas("story.pdf")
add_textfield(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Is there a way to create a textfield with the possibility to write multiple lines in it ?

Answer (score 1):

`reportlab.pdfbase.pdfform` has `textFieldAbsolute` and `textFieldRelative` functions which have `multiline` argument

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform

canvas = canvas.Canvas("story.pdf")

pdfform.textFieldAbsolute(canvas, 'test', maxlen=1000, x=50, y=500, width=500, height=300, multiline=1)

canvas.showPage()
canvas.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fieldFlags`-argument.

So your code will look as following.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def add_textfield(c):
    c.acroForm.textfield('test', maxlen=1000, x=50, y=500, width=500,
                         height=300, fieldFlags='multiline')

c = canvas.Canvas("story.pdf")
add_textfield(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```